# Securing a Spring Boot REST service using Oauth2 and Keycloak

Tags: rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I've successfully been able to secure a Spring Boot REST service using the keycloak Spring Boot adaptors and a Keycloak identity provider. However we now wish to attempt the same thing thing without using Keycloak adaptors but using Oauth2 directly. This is so that we can potentially connect to any identity provider in the future. I've tried various approaches but so far have had no success.

Has anybody been able to secure a Spring Boot REST service using the KeyCloak identity provider with Oauth2 rather than the Keycloak Spring Boot adapters?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the various approaches and what failed ?

Comment: test this. it helped me:
https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-boot-2-keycloak-oauth-example/